# Automatic mounting of cifs after every reboot on centos

Tags: linux

I have a requirement to mount the network drive after every reboot

sudo mount -t cifs hostname - doing this manually right now

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.